# Symbolized Crash Reports on Debug Build

Tags: ios, xcode

There is a build setting that says "Symbols Hidden By Default" that I have set to NO on my Debug build, but I'm still not getting symbolized crashes on my devices. Is this just not possible on ios ?. I know that on mac it is, but maybe there is another setting I'm missing ?
Thank you.

Comment: How are you trying to get symbolized crash reports?

Comment: Directly from xcode, when connecting the device on the organizer window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbolication will only work, if you did not start another build process after deploying a build onto your device. Each build will generate a unique combination of app binary and dSYM file with the same UUIDs. This ID is set in the crash report and used to find the correct dSYM to resolve the symbols in the crash report.

If you build again, these files get replaced and because of that get a new UUID also. So the symbolication process can not find the corresponding files and will not resolve the app specific symbols. The iOS symbols should work fine though.

Comment: Ok, I think i get it. I'm constantly building against debug on my devices and the simulator. But If I create a new scheme just for device testing then those builds with the dSYM should be left alone

Comment: I think a new scheme and new configuration

Comment: Configuration and device target together are unique. So if you change any of both, it gets written somewhere else. If you go to the organizer, projects, select the project, click on the arrow right of Derived data it will open a finder window. Then choose the Build subdirectory, then Products. This is where the binaries and dSYM files are located. You'll see one directory per configuration and device target.